# Search and save the string between two string

Tags: c#

I want to get the below string from the log file,

```
Name: OnError
Computer: 
Operator: 
Source Name: 
Source GUID: 
Execution GUID: 
Message: A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'xyz', Name of 'abc'.
Start Time: 2016-09-29 05:40:08
End Time: 2016-09-29 05:40:08
End Log
```

My keyword to search the string is `OnError`. From the string `OnError` to `End Log` i need to take and have to store in array.

Please give your suggestion for write the above code

Comment: Is it at all possible for the Message: portion of the string to contain the text "End Log" within that part?

Comment: No hatchet. The Message portion won't have the "End Log" text into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetData(string filePath)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool flag = false;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (line.Contains("OnError") || flag)
            {
                sb.Append(line);
                sb.AppendLine();
                flag = true;

            }

            if (line.Contains("End Log"))
            {
                flag = false;
            }

        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you have only one occurrence(OnError and End Log) of the given pattern in this example. You can expand it if there are multiple occurrences of this pattern. First find the line contains OnError and then read till the line which contains End Log.

Comment: @VigneshR now you time to payback:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex to do it easily

```
Regex regex = new Regex("OnError(.*)End Log");
var matches = regex.Matches(yourString);

foreach(Match match in matches)
    ....
```

Comment: Does this ensure that "End Log" is at the beginning of a new line?

Comment: Thanks Steve for your inputs. let me try this.

Comment: No Steve. The "End Log" will be end of the step in log file which will be look like "Log: Name: Computer: ...... End Log"

Comment: @VigneshR That's not what you stated in your post. You said your first key word is OnError, and it grabs everything up to "End Log", that's not inclusive. If you want to be inclusive, then just add that as part of the match, or simply add the string afterwords.